# Logging in Django does not work when using uWSGI

Tags: django, logging, uwsgi

I have a problem logging into a file using python built-in module.

Here is an example of how logs are generated:

```
logging.info('a log message')
```

Logging works fine when running the app directly through Python. However when running the app through uWSGI, logging does not work.

Here is my uWSGI configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
module = myapp.app:application
master = true
processes = 5

uid = nginx
socket = /run/uwsgi/myapp.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

logto = /var/log/myapp/myapp.log
logfile-chown = nginx:nginx
logfile-chmod = 640
```

**EDIT:**

The path `/var/log/myapp/myapp.log` is logging nginx access logs. There is another path configured in a `settings.py` file. The 2nd path is where application logs are ment to go. But there are non when using uWSGI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `logfile-chown = nginx:nginx` means the ownership of the logfile is being changed to `nginx`. That means, only `nginx` user can write to the file. However, your uwsgi process is most likely running as another user (maybe as `root` or your own username). Change it to the user which is running the uwsgi process. Also make sure you have write permission in `/var/log/myapp/` folder as well.

Comment: logto works but the output /var/log/myapp/myapp.log only contains nginx logs. I have another output which is not working. This output should contain application logs.